# AWS:Is my Elastic Beanstalk instance using ssd or magnetic storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In AWS I have a *Elastic Beanstalk* application that is using m3.medium instance, I went to configuration to see what disk my Root device is using, it says Container default and if I click on *Learn More* it says

> Each instance in your environment is configured with a root volume.
>   The root volume is the Amazon EBS block device attached to the
>   instance to store the operating system, libraries, scripts, and your
>   application source code. By default, all platforms use general purpose
>   SSD block devices for storage.

So it seems to be using SSD which is what I want, but if I go to EC2 and look at the volume attached to this ec2 server it says it is of type *standard* . And when I look at *volume types* help *standard* seems to refer to a defunct magnetic drive

So I'm unsure if I am using SSD or non SSD - I want to use SSD. I am also unclear that if I use the default volume do I pay for that like any other volumes or is it included in the price of the instance ?

**Update**

I  now changed configuration from *m3.medium* to *t2.medium*. After it had finished redeploying in EC2 volumes I noticed there was a new 8GB volume replacing the previous one (there were two volumes listed whilst redeploying was occurring), again this says *standard*, clicking on Elastic Beanstalk configuration notes it has *Root volume type* set to *(Container default)*. So again I am unclear is this SSD or magnetic ?

Comment: For your Elastic Beanstalk Environment, are you configuring it in the Console, using Saved Configurations, or .ebextensions?

Comment: Which Platform are you using? Are you using an old version of the solution stack?

Comment: @JamieStarke Created using Configuration and some have some ebextensions. I actually have two different elastic beanstalk apps, one uses ebextensions for root volume and one does not but both show the volume as standard in volumes